# Undefined reference to `omp_get_max_threads_'

Tags: gcc, openmp, gfortran

I'm getting the following errors trying to compile a project:
(fortran, using gfortran)

> undefined reference to `omp_get_max_threads_'
>
> undefined reference to `omp_get_thread_num_'

Problem is, my GCC version is 4.4.3, which was suppose to support OpenMP.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

With gcc, you need to compile and link with `-fopenmp` to enable OpenMP.   Other compilers have different options; with intel it's `-openmp`, with pgi it's `-mp`, etc.

Comment: WOW, you are right, I've just forgot to add it to the makefile aswell, I can't believe it lol...

Comment: Newer versions of Intel compilers have deprecated that option in favor of `-qopenmp`.

Comment: True, but how do you pass the flag -fopenmp to an IDE like CLion or Xcode?

Comment: CLion uses CMake, adding this to configuration file works for me: set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -fopenmp")
It is C settings only, C++ needs CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS.

Answer (score 23):

The code needs to be compiled with `-fopenmp`.

Answer (score 3):

gcc -program.c -o obj -fopenmp