# Hybrid MPI OpenMP "undefined reference to omp_set/get_num_threads"

Tags: c, mpi, openmp

I am trying to run a simple program that utilizes an MPI/OpenMP hybrid.

I compiled it on a Unix-based x86 cluster server with

```
mpic++ -openmp Hybrid_Print_Num_Threads.c -o test
```

but the compilation fails with an error

```
undefined reference to omp_set/get_num_threads
```

I've successfully run both MPI and OpenMP programs on this cluster in the past.

Code:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#define _NUM_THREADS 4 
/*  Each MPI process spawns a distinct OpenMP
 *  master thread; so limit the number of MPI 
 *  processes to one per node
 */
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
 int p,my_rank,c;
 /* set number of threads to spawn */
 omp_set_num_threads(_NUM_THREADS);

 /* initialize MPI stuff */
 MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
 MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&p);
 MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&my_rank);

 /* the following is a parallel OpenMP
  * executed by each MPI process
  */

 #pragma omp parallel reduction(+:c)
 {
   c = omp_get_num_threads();
 }

 /* expect a number to get printed for each MPI process */
 printf("%d\n",c);
 /* finalize MPI */
 MPI_Finalize();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Assuming your mpic++ is based on g++, correct spelling would be -fopenmp.  Any of several commands like mpic++ -v would help identify as would full error msg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined reference to \`omp\_get\_max\_threads\_'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685377/undefined-reference-to-omp-get-max-threads)

Comment: @tim18 beautiful, thank you.

Comment: @cdarke you're right, should I delete this question then?

Comment: Although your problem had been solved, you should also now that when you are using MPI + threads you should use `int MPI_Init_thread( int *argc, char ***argv, int required, int *provided )` for MPI initialization.