# Compiling on linux Intel Fortran without applying OpenMP to all programs

Tags: linux, fortran, openmp, intel-fortran

I have a main program file, let's call it mainprog.f90, and two module files - modules1.f90 and modules2.f90.

mainprog.f90 is written using OpenMP parallelization. The problem is that modules1.f90 and modules2.f90 contain Pure subroutines.

OpenMP is incompatible with pure subroutines. Compiling a program that contains pure subroutines with OpenMP gives an error.

Since the modules are called in the main code, the three programs need to be compiled in one command.

I'm trying to compile these programs in a terminal in Linux.
On Windows, with the use of Visual Studio, I didnt have a problem: I was able to set it so OpenMP would only be applied to mainprog.f90 and not to the module files.

What I'm wondering if there is some sort of terminal command to tell it to apply -qopenmp only to mainprog.f90 and not to the module files.

If there's no other way I will try to install Eclipse IDE and see if that will work, but I was wondering if there is a way to do this from the Terminal.

What do you suggest?

Here is the command I used first:

```
ifort modules1.f90 modules2.f90 mainprog.f90 -qopenmp -o name.out
```

I get an error, because it's not possible to use OpenMP with pure subroutines.

I also tried this:

```
ifort -c modules1.f90 modules2.f90 -o mod.o

ifort -c mainprog.f90 -qopenmp

ifort mod.o mainprog.o
```

This didn't work, it gave me errors as if I never used -qopenmp on mainprog.f90.
The errors were along the lines of

```
undefined reference to omp_get_thread_num in mainprog.f90
```

I guess I could remove the pure procedures, but this code wasn't written by me, and it is long so I don't understand it 100% yet. I'm not sure if changing the pure subroutines into regular ones wouldn't cause issues.

Comment: Add the `-qopenmp` flag to the link line.

Comment: In the linked answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685377/undefined-reference-to-omp-get-max-threads the key is in the "**and link**" with the `-qopenmp` flag words. It must also be added to your last `ifort mod.o mainprog.o` command and put the flag in front of your file names. Most flags should go in front of the file names.